# How to limit number of records in listview in android getting records from php

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I am getting Json records from my php script which connects to Mysql.
At a time php script sends  500 records.
Then these records are converted to array and a listview is generated with all 500 records.
I wanted listview to display 20 records at a time and when user reaches bottom of the listview next 20 records should be displayed.

the code bieng used for this activity is

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
final String LOG = "ListActivity";

private ArrayList<Product> productList;
private ListView lvProduct;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(ListActivity.this));

    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(ListActivity.this, this);
    taskRead.execute("http:///product.php");

}

@Override
public void processFinish(String s) {
    productList = new JsonConverter<Product>().toArrayList(s, Product.class);

    BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvName, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
            return product.name;
        }
    });


    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPrice, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
            return "" + product.v;
        }
    });
    dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImage,
            new StringExtractor<Product>() {
                @Override
                public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
                    return product.youtubeid;
                }
            }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
                @Override
                public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {


                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView);
                }
            });

    FunDapter<Product> adapter = new FunDapter<>(
            ListActivity.this, productList, R.layout.layout_list, dict);

    lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProduct);
    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Product selectedProduct = productList.get(position);
    Intent in = new Intent(ListActivity.this, Detailactivity.class);
    in.putExtra("product", (Serializable) selectedProduct);
    startActivity(in);
}
}
```

Comment: you could add all of these 500 records to an array and get 20 at a time from the array just keeping where you stopped for the next quarry to the list.

Comment: thanks how will i get 20 at a time from array this is exactly what i wanted to know

Comment: Have a key like int i = 0 declared outside of the button press. Once the button is pressed then update the key by 20 and then reuse the key as the next starting point when you want the rest of the data